# Группировка массива объектов

Tags: javascript, массивы, объекты

Имеется массив объектов. Необходимо сгруппировать его по одному из ключей объекта.

```
const foods = [
  {id: 1, title: 'apple', type: 'fruit'},
  {id: 2, title: 'banana', type: 'fruit'},
  {id: 3, title: 'bird', type: 'meat'},
  {id: 4, title: 'beer', type: 'drinks'},
  {id: 5, title: 'cow', type: 'meat'},
]
```

Должен получиться следующий результат:

```
const foodTypes = [
  {
    type: 'fruit', 
    foods: [
      {id: 1, title: 'apple', type: 'fruit'},
      {id: 2, title: 'banana', type: 'fruit'},
    ]
  },
  {
    type: 'meat', 
    foods: [
      {id: 3, title: 'cow', type: 'meat'},
      {id: 4, title: 'bird', type: 'meat'},
    ]
  },
  {
    type: 'drinks', 
    foods: [
      {id: 5, title: 'beer', type: 'drinks'},
    ]
  },
]
```

Comment: Добро пожаловать на «StackOverflow на русском»! [**Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос**. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и **укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности** при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: `let foodTypes = Object.values(foods.reduce((acc, cur) =>  ({ ...acc, [cur.type]: [...acc[cur.type] || [], cur] })
, {} )).reduce((acc, cur) => [...acc, {type: cur[0].type, foods: cur}], []);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В result положим все совпадения по type,
далее создадим шаблон обьекта, который будем добавлять в foodTypes, и каждый найденный результат в result будем добавлять в object.foods , в конце функция добавит наш обьект в foodTypes.

```
 const foodTypes = [];
    
    function groupMassive(value) {
      const result = foods.filter((item) => {
        return item.type.includes(value);
      });
      const object = {
        type: "",
        foods: [],
      };
      object.type = result[0].type;
      result.forEach((item) => object.foods.push(item));
      foodTypes.push(object);
    }
    groupMassive("fruit");
    groupMassive("meat");
    groupMassive("drinks");
```

Если хотим автоматизировать, то создадим вторую функцию которая вернёт готовый массив

```
function returnMassive(massive) 
{
const types = massive.filter(item => item.type)

types.forEach(type => groupMassive(type)) 
}
```

returnMassive(foods)

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Большое спасибо. Ваш способ работает. Ещё попробовал решить через метод reduce, тоже получилось.

Comment: @Andrew Опубликуйте свой вариант решения для будущих поколений )

Answer (score 0):

Вот рабочий вариант через reduce

```js
const foods = [
  {id: 1, title: 'apple', type: 'fruit'},
  {id: 2, title: 'banana', type: 'fruit'},
  {id: 3, title: 'bird', type: 'meat'},
  {id: 4, title: 'beer', type: 'drinks'},
  {id: 5, title: 'cow', type: 'meat'},
]

const grouper = key => array => 
  Object.values(array.reduce((acc,val) => {
    const property = val[key];
    acc[property] = acc[property] || {
      type: property,
      foods: []
    };
    acc[property].foods.push(val);
    return acc;
  },{}))

console.log(JSON.stringify((grouper('type')(foods)), null,2))
```